# Uploading a files in a folder to FTP using Python ftplib

Tags: python, ftp, upload, ftplib

I'm trying to upload a bunch of files contained in a single directory.

The code does not fail but does not seems to work either.

My code so far is as follows:

```
import ftplib

FTP_HOST = "host"
FTP_USER = "user"
FTP_PASS = "pass"

ftp = ftplib.FTP(FTP_HOST, FTP_USER, FTP_PASS)
ftp.encoding = "utf-8"

dirFTP = "dirPath"
toFTP = os.listdir(dirFTP)

for filename in toFTP:
    filePath = os.path.join(dirFTP, filename)
    with open(filePath, "rb") as file:
        ftp.storbinary(f"STOR {filePath}", file)

ftp.quit()
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add `print(toFtp)` before the loop, or run under debugger and inspect there..

Comment: Martin Prikryl: that's exactly the description, the code does not fails but does not the work it is supposed to either.
The second path is not the remote path, is the local path of the single file to upload.

PM 77-1: will try to get the problem there. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. Didn't know that.
I'm aboslutely new at this and have not external help for coding this.
If this bothers you, you are more than welcome to not answer next time.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. I got my code working properly.

Code is:

```
import ftplib

FTP_HOST = "host"
FTP_USER = "user"
FTP_PASS = "pass"

ftp = ftplib.FTP(FTP_HOST, FTP_USER, FTP_PASS)
ftp.encoding = "utf-8"

dirFTP = "dirPath"
toFTP = os.listdir(dirFTP)

for filename in toFTP:
    with open(os.path.join(dirFTP,filename), 'rb') as file:  #Here I open the file using it's  full path
        ftp.storbinary(f'STOR {filename}', file)  #Here I store the file in the FTP using only it's name as I intended

ftp.quit()
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: you are welcome, bro